# How to get ARN (Amazon Resource Name)?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS Resource Tagging API (.Net) to add tags to AWS Resources. The problem I've is that Tagging API uses `ARNs` as identifiers for resources, however when I download resources, the only Id I've is an InstanceId. Is there a way, based on `InstanceId`, to get `ARN` or do I need to construct it manually ?