# How do you determine the ARN of a Redshift cluster via the AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-sdk

I'm trying to add tags to a Redshift cluster using CreateTags, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTags.html and you'll notice it requires an ARN for the resource.

But when you call DescribeClusters, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeClusters.html no ARN is returned.

Is there some other API call to retrieve the ARN or do I have to construct it manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804771/how-to-get-arn-amazon-resource-name

Answer (score 22):

The ARN format is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-redshift). Specifically for a Redshift cluster the ARN format is:

```
arn:aws:redshift:region:account-id:cluster:cluster-name
```

If you know the region, account-id and cluster-name then you can construct the ARN.

Comment: Is the implication that you have to assemble this one manually? The other AWS services return fully constructed ARNs for resources.

Comment: The implication is that you can easily construct them manually.

Comment: Shouldn't this be displayed in the AWS console when viewing the cluster? I cannot find it.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs Yes, it should be displayed, yet here we are 3 years later and it still doesn't appear to be visible in the AWS Console.

Comment: I don't see it in my console! every single resource beside redshift displays an arn.

Comment: So annoying AWS doesn't display the ARN. It's the little things like these that make me doubt the modern IT industry :)

Answer (score 1):

The cluster ARN is now displayed within the Management Console's *General Information* pane (*Amazon Redshift* **->** *Clusters* **->** *'cluster-name'*), and includes an identifier for the cluster's `namespace`:

```
arn:aws:redshift:region:<account_number>:namespace:<cluster_namespace_id>
```